# Best way to work with Bitmaps

Tags: java, android, bitmap, garbage-collection

I am using Bitmaps for each preview frame taken from the camera like this:

```
int[] buffer = ...;
decodeYUV420SP(buffer, data, width, height);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(buffer, width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

Where `data` is the buffer from the `onPreviewFrame`
(I reason for doing that is to workaround [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36905470), closed as "won't fix"). So far so good.

Now in android 2.3.3, I know I can simply call `bitmap.recycle` to free allocated memory to reduce the GC time. Since API level 11 (android 3.0) the policy [has changed](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html) and the `bitmap.recycle` call does nothing. Instead, it' recommended use `BitmapFactory.Options` to specify the bitmap to load the image into. But it works *only* for reading compressed images from the streams, `Bitmap.createBitmap` above does not accept a `BitmapFactory.Options` instance. `Bitmap.setPixels` does accepts a color array, but in another format, and the decoding is not clear.

I may be wrong, but I don't see *any way* to create a `Bitmap` having a color buffer effectively in terms of memory in Android 3.0. A new heavy instance is always created and it can't be recycled.

I will be very glad to know that the task can be done effectively.

Comment: To clarify, what goes wrong when using the `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` method that accepts an `Options` parameter?

Comment: The `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` just returns null, which is expected because the image data is not compressed.